# Replace partial derivatives in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I'm learning perturbation in SymPy. Let's say I have an expression U(X,Y) = 0, where U is a function of X and Y. The function has no closed-form solution for Y, so I approximate it with a Taylor expansion around a known solution by taking first, second, third, etc. derivatives of my expression with respect to X, where I take into account that Y is a function of X:

dU(X,Y(X))/dX = U_X + U_Y * Y_X

To find Y_X I need to replace U_X and U_Y by their values at the known solution. The following SymPy code, however...

```
from sympy import *

X, b = symbols('X b')
U = Function('U')
Y = Function('Y')(X)

diff1 = diff(U(X,Y))
print diff1
```

...gives me the following output:

```
Derivative(U(X, Y(X)), X) +
Derivative(Y(X), X)*Subs(Derivative(U(X, _xi_2), _xi_2), (_xi_2,), (Y(X),))
```

I know how to replace `Derivative(Y(X), X)` by, say, the variable `b`:

```
diff1.subs({diff(Y,X):b})
b*Subs(Derivative(U(X, _xi_2), _xi_2), (_xi_2,), (Y(X),)) + 
Derivative(U(X, Y(X)), X)
```

If I would have the numerical values of U_X (`Derivative(U(X, y(X)), X)`) and U_Y (`Subs(Derivative(U(X, _xi_2), _xi_2), (_xi_2,), (Y(X),))`) I could solve this for `b` and then I have my estimate of Y_X, but how do I replace these partial derivatives by some numerical value?

In response to the first comment: one solution is indeed to use the explicit form of U, for example

```
X, b = symbols('X b')
Y = Function('Y')(X)
U = (X**0.5)*(Y**0.5)-100

diff1 = diff(U,X)
diff1 = diff1.subs({diff(Y,X):b,Y:100,X:100})
sol1 = solve(diff1,b)[0]

diff2 = diff(U,X,2)
diff2 = diff2.subs({diff(Y,X,2):b,diff(Y,X):sol1,Y:100,X:100})
sol2 = solve(diff2,b)[0]

diff3 = diff(U,X,3)
diff3 = diff3.subs({diff(Y,X,3):b,diff(Y,X,2):sol2,diff(Y,X):sol1,Y:100,X:100})
sol3 = solve(diff3,b)[0]
```

And so on. Note that the first variable to be replaced is the derivative of interest; it is replaced by a dummy variable that enables one to solve the expression. Then all the other derivatives (for which values are known from previous steps) are replaced; then parameters and variables are replaced. This does work, but I had hoped there would have been a more elegant way to do this. Apparently not.

Comment: Presumably you have a formula for U? Otherwise this isn't getting anywhere.